# Relacion Uno a Uno DB y como se mapea en JPA

Tags: java, base-de-datos, jpa, relaciones

hoy me he hecho un lio haciendo un ejecrcio de base de datos con una relacion uno a uno

Tengo dos unidades de negocio, Universidades y Bibliotecas donde una universidad solo tiene una bilioteca. En mi modelo de dominio (que creo o considero debe ser) veo esto regla de negocio de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Universidad{
  private int idUniversidad;
  private String nombre;
  private Biblioteca biblioteca;
  //constructor y demas getter y setter
}

public class Biblioteca {
  private int idBiblioteca;
  private String nombre;
}
```

Ahora bien, para la base de datos he buscado el como hacer una relación uno a uno y he encontrado varias formas

**Con llaves foraneas Universidad --> Biblioteca**

```
create table UNIVERSIDADES(
  idUniversidad int not null,
  nombre varchar2(64) not null,
  constraint PK_UNIVERSIDADES primary key (idUniversidad)
);

create table BIBLIOTECAS(
  idBiblioteca int not null,
  nombre varchar2(64) not null,
  idUniversidad int not null,
  constraint PK_BIBLIOTECAS primary key (idBiblioteca),
  constraint FK_UNIVERSIDADES_BIBLIOTECAS foreign key (idUniversidad) references UNIVERSIDADES(idUniversidad),
  constraint UK_UNIVERSIDAD unique (idUniversidad)
);
```

**Con llaves foraneas Biblioteca --> Universidad**

```
create table BIBLIOTECAS(
  idBiblioteca int not null,
  nombre varchar2(64) not null,
  constraint PK_BIBLIOTECAS primary key (idBiblioteca)
);

create table UNIVERSIDADES(
  idUniversidad int not null,
  nombre varchar2(64) not null,
  idBiblioteca int not null,
  constraint PK_UNIVERSIDADES primary key (idUniversidad),
  constraint FK_BIBLIOTECAS_UNIVERSIDADES foreign key (idBiblioteca) references UNIVERSIDADES(idUniversidad),
  constraint UK_BIBLIOTECA unique (idBiblioteca)
);
```

La otra forma que encontre es la de usar la misma llave primaria en las dos tablas pero no deseo abordar ese esquema.

Mi pregunta es cual de las dos formas es mejor abordar que se adapte al modelo de dominio, que creo es el correcto, y como serian sus anotaciones JPA.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Son validas ambas, yo personalmente pondría un FK de la biblioteca en la universidad, ya que por ejemplo si quisieras extender el modelo no solo en universidades sino en otro tipo de instituciones que tengan biblioteca solo agregas la FK de la biblioteca a la nueva institución

En univesidad pones

```
@OneToOne 
@JoinColumn(name = "biblioteca_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Biblioteca biblioteca;
```

siendo biblioteca_id el nombre del atributo en Universidad y id el nombre de la columna en biblioteca

Comment: Lucas, muchas gracias por la respuesta, lo deje de forma "más común" por así decirlo, cree la Universidad, y a la biblioteca le adicione una llave foranea de la universidad y adicione un constraint para que esta fuera unica.